# Not connecting to sites intermittently

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi

So, my Macbook Pro is connected to Wifi and I am getting around 70Mbps. But after every few minutes, it's like there is no internet available. Wifi is still connected but all the pages are not loading at all, video streaming would stop etc.

- If I turn on & off my Wifi connection, it will work but after sometime this issue will start again.
- I am not seeing this issue on my mobile which is also connected to Wifi.
- One thing I noticed that even the local server running on my machine is not able to serve static files during this time which made me think this has to do something with my machine.
- I can still ping google.com but I can't curl and get the html at this time.
- This issue started few hours back and previously it working without any issues with the same modem and same wifi connection.

**Edit**

OS: macOS High Sierra v10.13.6

Comment: What version of macOS are you using?

Comment: we need numbers not just words in order to help you. Report WiFi during both times, hold option key and click on WiFi, then screenshot it and post. Thank you.

Comment: @Buscar웃 What numbers would you want to see in the screenshots?

Comment: @abc added OS info.

Comment: Add a speedtest when you have normal speed and a speedtest when you have slow speed